# Language: C; Single scanf() for 1 or 2 inputs

Tags: c, buffer, scanf

**What's necessary:**

Single scanf()* statement that can accommodate 2 types of input and assign them to before initialized variable/s.

*Or any other function/way that can do what's necessary.

**Types of Input:**

1. `%c %i` - Example: c 56
2. `%c`    - Example: c

**The Current Problem:**

`scanf("%c %i", &c, &i);` - Must specify `%i`, however there are cases of no second argument `%i`.

**Examples of possible input:**

- c 567 (same line)
- i 21 (same line)
- h

Comment: you can't. Just read the line using `fgets` and use `sscanf` from there.

Comment: What is the reason for needing to do this in a single `scanf()`?  If another function is acceptable, then you can write your own easily enough that bolts together logic that includes multiple `scanf()` calls (or whatever).  That's what programming is.

Comment: And what have you tried?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you could read the line using `fgets`, then use `sscanf` which isn't interactive, count how many fields you've successfully parsed, and act accordignly:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
 char buffer[100];
 char c;
 int i;

 fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), stdin);
 int nb_toks = sscanf(buffer,"%c %i", &c, &i);
 switch (nb_toks)
 {
 case 2:
    printf("%c %i\n",c,i);
    break;
 case 1:
    printf("%c\n",c);
    break;
 default:
   /* some error management */
 }

}
```